# UIScrollview with Autolayout Content Size in Landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I'm trying to show a simple settings screen in my app and I'm using Autolayout.  Since my app supports landscape, and the settings controls don't quite fit vertically when the phone is landscape, I added a UIScrollview.

It seems that the combination of UIScrollview and Autolayout is a common question here and elsewhere.  I've read a few articles on it, and from what it can tell, it seems that a good way to go for what I'm trying to do is to put my various controls within a view, like a "contentView" with constraints aligned in that view.  Then have that contentView be the sole subview of the UIScrollView.  I have the contentView with constraints tied to the edges of the UIScrollView.

```
UINavigationView -> UIScrollview -> contentView (UIView) -> Control Subviews
```

[image: xib]

It works fine in portrait, even if I add content in my contentView that requires scrolling to see, but when I go to landscape, it doesn't let me scroll down far enough. It's like the content size gets reset to the frame of the visible area (or the frame of the navigation controller superview) when I rotate.

[image: simulator]

I'm wondering if I need to check for rotation and then set the content size again at that time?  If so, is there a way to get that size dynamically from the view (contentView)?

Thanks for any help you can offer!
Jim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two components to having auto layout properly handle scroll views:

1. Constraints for scroll view's subviews: The `contentSize` of the scroll view will be dictated by the constraints of the scroll view's subviews. Thus, you need to have a bottom constraint for the last control in the scroll view (i.e. second switch) to its superview (i.e. the scroll view). It looks like you do have this. These constraints for subviews of the scroll view will automatically adjust the scroll view's `contentSize` as needed.

   By the way, the `constant` for this second switch's bottom constraint will generally default to some largish value corresponding to how it was laid out in portrait. You may want to select and edit this bottom constraint for this last control and change it so that it's the "standard" value.

   [image]
2. Constraints for the scroll view itself: You need to make sure you have the bottom constraint for the scroll view, itself, to its superview (and make sure you do *not* have a height constraint on the scroll view). This will adjust the `frame` of the scroll view upon screen rotation. I wonder if this might be missing in your project.

   You can confirm this by running your app in the debugger, hitting "pause" button:

   [image]

   and then at the `(lldb)` prompt, type `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`, and you should see something like:

   ```
   (lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
   <UIWindow: 0x8b97ff0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8b98450>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8b97af0>>
      | <UIView: 0x8b9a830; frame = (0 0; 320 480); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9a240>>
      |    | <UIScrollView: 0x8b9aa50; frame = (0 0; 480 320); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+TM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8b9a6c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9a130>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
      |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8b9ade0; frame = (20 20; 63 21); text = 'Settings'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9aec0>>
      |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8b9d590; frame = (20 49; 51 21); text = 'View 1'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9d6b0>>
      |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8b9db70; frame = (408 49; 51 21); text = 'View 2'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9dc10>>
      |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b9de60; frame = (335 78; 124 53); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9dec0>>
      |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b9e000; frame = (20 78; 284 53); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9e060>>
      |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8b9e250; frame = (20 139; 59 21); text = 'Slider 1'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9e2f0>>
      |    |    | <UISlider: 0x8b9e460; frame = (18 238; 444 34); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9e5c0>; value: 0.500000>
      |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8ace410; frame = (2 16; 440 2); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ace470>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8ace610; frame = (221 0; 219 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ace670>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8ace6e0; frame = (-221 0; 440 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ace740>>
      |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CAGradientLayer: 0x8ace7b0> (layer)
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8ace7e0; frame = (0 0; 221 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ace840>>
      |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8ace9d0; frame = (207 1; 31 31); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8acea60>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8ace8b0; frame = (-13 -6.5; 57 43.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ace940>>
      |    |    | <UISlider: 0x8b9e850; frame = (17 168; 444 34); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9e930>; value: 0.500000>
      |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8ba5430; frame = (2 16; 440 2); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ba5490>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8acc190; frame = (221 0; 219 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8acae30>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8acc3f0; frame = (-221 0; 440 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ac84d0>>
      |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CAGradientLayer: 0x8accb90> (layer)
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8acdf50; frame = (0 0; 221 2); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8acdfb0>>
      |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8ace070; frame = (207 1; 31 31); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ace100>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8acdfe0; frame = (-13 -6.5; 57 43.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8acdc80>>
      |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8b9e9c0; frame = (20 209; 59 21); text = 'Slider 2'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9ea60>>
      |    |    | <UISwitch: 0x8b9ece0; frame = (411 279; 51 31); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9edd0>>
      |    |    |    | <_UISwitchInternalViewNeueStyle1: 0x8b9f0c0; frame = (0 0; 51 31); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8b723f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9f1c0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b9f750; frame = (35.5 0; 15.5 31); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9f7b0>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b9f3b0; frame = (-35.5 0; 51 31); layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9f410>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b9f6c0; frame = (0 0; 35.5 31); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9f720>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b9f440; frame = (0 0; 51 31); layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9f4a0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8ba11e0; frame = (0 0; 51 31); layer = <CALayer: 0x8ba1240>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8ba0f10; frame = (39 16; 0 0); alpha = 0; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ba10f0>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8ba1120; frame = (12 16; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ba11b0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8b9fab0; frame = (7 -6; 57 43.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ba0a40>>
      |    |    | <UISwitch: 0x8b974b0; frame = (411 318; 51 31); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b75570>>
      |    |    |    | <_UISwitchInternalViewNeueStyle1: 0x8b7d6a0; frame = (0 0; 51 31); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8b845e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b78750>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b7df70; frame = (35.5 0; 15.5 31); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b7be00>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b72410; frame = (-35.5 0; 51 31); layer = <CALayer: 0x8b7a660>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b7ba80; frame = (0 0; 35.5 31); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b7bd00>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b78dd0; frame = (0 0; 51 31); layer = <CALayer: 0x8b7ba20>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x8b81580; frame = (0 0; 51 31); layer = <CALayer: 0x8b77ee0>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8b97880; frame = (39 16; 0 0); alpha = 0; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b7e1a0>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8b77460; frame = (12 16; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b7e350>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8b80670; frame = (7 -6; 57 43.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b80700>>
      |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8b97cf0; frame = (335 284; 67 21); text = 'Switch 1'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b808b0>>
      |    |    | <UILabel: 0x8b79d60; frame = (335 323; 67 21); text = 'Switch 2'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b77b90>>
      |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8ac44f0; frame = (476 473; 3 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a89130>>
      |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x8ac2be0; frame = (313 316; 7 3); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ac2c70>>
      |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x8b9cb20; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8b9e5f0>>
      |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x8ac4440; frame = (0 320; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x8a90370>>
   ```

   Check the `frame` of the `UIScrollView` (e.g. the above is for landscape on iPhone), and make sure it corresponds to the size of screen. If you haven't defined the constraints between the scroll view and its superview, this `frame` may be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

I hadn't tried that recursive output prompt from the debugger before, so that was a cool trick.  On difference in your sample from mine was that I had an intermediate UIView (I called it "contentView") between my UIScrollView and my sliders and switches, etc.  

That said, the big tip seemed to be removing the height constraint from the scroll view.  Once I removed that, I was able to scroll all the way down in Portrait.  In fact it went past the content (maybe still the size of the portrait), but at least i can get to the content!  Thanks...

Comment: I meant after removing the vertical height constraint of the scrollview I was able to scroll all the way (even past) the content in <i>Landscape</i> mode.  I may need to force some kind of refresh on the "contentView" when the orientation changes to get the contentsize to match exactly, but too tall is better than too short.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Jim The "it went past the content" issue could be a function of what the bottom constraint of that switch was to the container view, and the constraint from the bottom of the container view to the bottom of the scroll view. It's hard to say without seeing the project. Bottom line, if you get your constraints right, you definitely don't need to be messing around with `contentSize` on orientation changes.

Comment: Thanks Rob- I will check that out.  You had the key with regard to removing that vertical height constraint and it looks like the rest will work with some tweaking of other constraints.  Thanks to @Marcelo Gobetti too for the tip on reacting to changes.  That may come in handy later.  Also, Rob I'm now off to look for more info on some of that command line debugging to look at frames and layouts.  Let me know if you know of a good resource and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe others will have a better solution for this, but the fastest without changing too much on your current build would be to do exactly what you said: *check for rotation and then set the content size again*.
It would be done like this in your *Settings View Controller* implementation file:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
}
```

... assuming you have added in that same file outlets to your `UIScrollView` and your `UIView` named `scrollView` and `contentView` respectively.