# Evenly spaced UIButtons in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, interface-builder, constraints

Is there a simple way to evenly space two UIButtons horizontally across a UIScrollView in iOS?

See images for example. Notice how buttons are wider in landscape orientation.

I want:

1. The buttons to fill all the available horizontal space.
2. To have equal width buttons.
3. To not cause the UIScrollView to scroll horizontally.
4. To automatically resize when flipping from portrait to landscape.
5. To preferably use Interface Builder constraints only, but I'll use code if necessary.

[image: Btns during portrait orientation]

[image: Btns during landscape orientation]

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout, or the old-school springs and struts?

Comment: Auto Layout.  iOS7.  Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using autoLayout it should be fairly simple:

First, you need to make sure that you have your top, bottom, leading, and trailing constraints set on both buttons.  (Keep in mind that your leading and trailing constraints are what's important here.  You may have to tweak your top and bottom spacing constraints so that the height of the button doesn't resize on rotation.)

Once you have done that, select both buttons using cmd+click, and then click the box to add another autolayout constraint, and select "Equal Widths":

[image: Autolayout Screenshot]

**EDIT:** My initial example was made inside UIView, and I didn't initially consider that the UIScrollView's contentSize is determined by the last element in its subviews.  [Here is a related question regarding handling autolayout for a UIScrollView in landscape.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206789/uiscrollview-with-autolayout-content-size-in-landscape)  Once you are able to modify your scrollview's contentSize on rotation, the autolayout on your buttons should work.

Comment: Did that.  But that causes the UIScrollView to scroll horizontally.  The buttons get wider, and evidently the UIScrollView contentsize widens.  The buttons do not resize when switched to landscape. (Each button has four constraints, plus the equal width constraint mentioned above.)

Comment: I've edited my initial response based on your comments.  Please let me know if the provided link is of any help.

Comment: Setting the UIScrollView contentSize does not help.  It simply clips the second button so you cannot scroll to it's right edge.  I'm thinking that you cannot constrain anything to the right edge of a UIScrollView.  In other words, you cannot force a subview to move to the right edge of a UIScrollView.  Is that incorrect? Is there some simple way that I've missed?

Comment: I continued looking into the problem last Thursday, but was unable to come up with a working example before the holiday weekend.  Usually I would say to try putting the buttons in a container view that is the size of your scrollview's contentView.  However, I'm still having issues getting the container to resize properly upon rotation.  I'll let you know if I come up with a working example.

Comment: I resorted to code to reposition the buttons because I believed that views could not be constrained to the right edge of a UIScrollView. I'm probably wrong about that.  I wanted this to be a 100% IB solution, but the code works.

Comment: At least you found a workaround for it.  You should either provide your own answer to the question or update your initial question so that anyone else who comes across this question can see what you did to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using code like this below because I could not find a way to constrain views to the right or bottom of a UIScrollView.  Such constraints seemed to only set the contentSize of the scroll view rather than moving or resizing subviews.

```
+ (void)resizeBtnsHorz:(UIButton*)btn1 Button2:(UIButton*)btn2
{
    if (btn1 == nil || btn2 == nil || btn1.superview == nil || btn2.superview == nil || btn1.superview != btn2.superview)
        return;

    int nSideMargins = 0;
    int nSpaceBetween = 10;
    int nTotalWidth = btn1.superview.frame.size.width;
    int nBtnSpace = nTotalWidth - (nSideMargins*2) - nSpaceBetween;
    int nBtnWidth = nBtnSpace / 2;

    // Remove from view so we can set new frame rects
    // Autolayout prevents this, so the buttons must be removed and readded
    UIView* view1 = btn1.superview;
    [btn1 removeFromSuperview];
    [btn2 removeFromSuperview];
    [btn1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    [btn2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

    // Button 1
    CGRect rBtn = btn1.frame;
    rBtn.origin.x = nSideMargins;
    rBtn.size.width = nBtnWidth;
    btn1.frame = rBtn;

    // Button 2
    rBtn = btn2.frame;
    rBtn.origin.x = nSideMargins + nBtnWidth + nSpaceBetween;
    rBtn.size.width = nBtnWidth;
    btn2.frame = rBtn;

    [view1 addSubview:btn1];
    [view1 addSubview:btn2];
}
```